Android Resource not found for ListPreference
I am doing a new app version for android TV. After upgrading every android & leanback libraries,and eliminating every deprecated functions, I am having an issue at the Settings Fragment which extends PreferenceFragmentCompat. Issue is, first, that the app crashes when including a ListPreference. Error shown is
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.tv, PID: 5348
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:225)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2446)
at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1252)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:536)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:485)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$AlertParams.createListView(AlertController.java:989)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$AlertParams.apply(AlertController.java:965)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:983)
at androidx.preference.PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat.onCreateDialog(PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat.java:161)
at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.prepareDialog(DialogFragment.java:665)
at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.onGetLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:579)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performGetLayoutInflater(Fragment.java:1752)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:493)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1899)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1823)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1760)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:547)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)

After so many hours investigating, I came up to a workaround, adding the following lines to the Acivity style,
<item name="dialogTheme">@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Dialog</item>
<item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Dialog</item>

Well, it does not crash anymore, but the ListPreference pops up instead sticking to the Settings Fragment (with the same colors as before). Instead, I get a floating gray ugly popup which is not what I want.
Here is my Activity, as simple as possible
public class ActSettings extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_settings);
    }
}

act_settings xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_150sdp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_home"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
            android:name="com.test.tv.fragment.FragmentSettings"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

So, this is my fragment's code
public class FragmentSettings extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
    }

}

with prefs.xml as following
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:key="prefs_screen"
    android:summary=""
    android:title="@string/settings">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="version_category"
        android:title="@string/app_version">
        <PreferenceScreen
            android:selectable="true"
            android:key="app_version"
            android:title="">
        </PreferenceScreen>
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="language_settings_category"
        android:title="@string/language">
        <ListPreference
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_translate_24px"
            android:key="prefs_language"
            app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true"
            android:title="@string/mod_language"
            android:entries="@array/pref_languages"
            android:entryValues="@array/pref_languages_values"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:selectable="true" />
        <PreferenceScreen
            android:selectable="false"
            android:key="prefs_need_restart"
            android:summary="@string/need_restart"
            android:title=""/>
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>

This image shows the activity, with the fragment docked to the right (blue frame). So I click at the language preference which is a ListPreference, and a gray popup shows. I need this ListPreference to show inside the fragment, using the same style, colors, etc as the parent fragment/activity
Not sure how to achieve this, nor I am not sure why I must specify a "dialogTheme" in order for my att not to crash.
Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:
As a workaround I am doing my preference layout manually using TextViews, RelativeLayouts, etc. Problem is when I add a SwitchCompat I get this error again:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.test.tv, PID: 6016
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.tv/com.test.tv.view.ActSettings}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:204)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2133)
at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1142)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:751)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:197)
at com.test.tv.view.ActCommon.onCreate(ActCommon.java:81)
at com.test.tv.view.ActSettings.onCreate(ActSettings.java:21)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)


Can you please share your output and mark where the issue is? I do not understand: I get a floating gray ugly popup which is not what I want.

Hello friend. I upoloaded a picture showing output. Maybe I uploaded wrong but it is a hyperlink with text "This image shows the activity..." THanks
